# Using Ubuntu GUI on cloud server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute Engine VM instance running Ubuntu 14.04.

I use command line through SSH so far to interact with the server.

How can I interact with the Ubuntu VM via a graphical interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the GCE VM instance via [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), see [this Medium article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5) for how to do this.

The overall flow is mostly the same as for any other Linux server:

- install a desktop environment
- install VNC server on the VM
- start the VNC server
- open firewall to allow clients to connect
- connect your local VNC client
- connect to VNC server

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641150/cant-vnc-into-google-compute-engine) for troubleshooting.